# Having problem with namespace

Tags: 8

I am writing a custom module, I am trying to use the `validateExtensions()` method defined from the Drupal core File module inside the [FileItem.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21FileItem.php/8.2.x) file, in my own controller, using the following code.

```
use Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileItem;

//Some other Use statement 

class someclass extends FormBase {
  $instance = new FileItem();
  //Some Code
  '#element_validate' => array(array(get_class($instance), 'validateExtensions')),
```

It gives the following error:

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemBase::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinitionInterface, none given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the error message:

FieldItemBase has a constructor, and it waits a parameter (actually multiple), but it doesn't get any:

```
$instance = new FileItem();
```

Even though the constructor function can't be find in FileItem, in this case you have to investigate which parent has it. You will find out that "FieldItemBase" has it. 
I don't know why you want to use this like this, but things like Controllers, Plugins, Services were mean to be to get instantiated by Drupal.